# Linux C API for CPU Usage

Tags: c, linux, api, cpu

I understand on Linux systems there is getrusage() API for finding the CPU usage for the current process. Is there an API like that for getting the system CPU usage in terms of percent? Or should I simply go for the solution discussed at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21564 where I manually read /proc/stat? What do software like htop and top use to find user, sys, idle, etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know /proc/stat is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

top interrogates /proc/stat, to the best of my knowledge there's no API for what you're asking.

Comment: I would rather say that `read(2)`-ing `/proc/stat` is *the* API to do that.